# deleting a usage plan using AWS SDK JavaScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to delete a usage plan using AWS SDK by invoking the deleteUsagePlan function and passing the usagePlanId param as follow:

```
  const params: AWSNXR.APIGateway.DeleteUsagePlanRequest = {
    usagePlanId: usage_plan_id,
  };

  const apigw = new AWS.APIGateway();

  const response = await apigw.deleteUsagePlan(params).promise();
```

But for some reason, I'm not able to do so and I'm getting this error back: BadRequestException: Cannot delete Usage Plan USAGE_PLAN_ID_HERE because there are API Stages associated with it, including API_ID_HERE:test

**Steps to reproduce:**

1- create a usage plan with the params below

name: "my_usage_plan",
apiStages: [
apiId: "API_ID_HERE",
stage: "test"
]

2- delete the usage plan

usagePlanId: USAGE_PLAN_ID

I kept getting an error in step #2 saying:
BadRequestException: Cannot delete Usage Plan USAGE_PLAN_ID_HERE because there are API Stages associated with it, including API_ID_HERE:test

**Expected behavior:**

the expected behavior is to be able to delete the newly created usage plan using the usage plan id

**Additional content:**

what I tried to fix this issue:
1- I tried deleting the test stage on the API gateway
2- I ran the delete usage plan function with the same usage plan id

the usage plan got deleted successfully without any error, however, I should be able to delete it without the need to delete a stage and re-creating it after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before deleting usage plan, you have to remove api stages, you can do this by calling updateUsagePlan as below:

```
const params = {
    usagePlanId: "{usage plan id}", 
    patchOperations: [{
        op: "remove",
        path: "/apiStages",
        value: "{api gw id}:{stage name}"
    }]
 };
const apigateway = new AWS.APIGateway();

await apigateway.updateUsagePlan(params).promise();
```

I couldn't find any documentation about it, only found solution by tracking network calls originating from aws console in browser.